# Programmatically Recomputing Precise Part Volume From Third-Party Files Using Forge APIs

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-inventor

**I'm looking for best practices and performance-guided recommendations for recomputing a model's volume when it's missing from the source file.** This is in the context of a web application I am working to build that enables:

1. Uploading 3D models in a variety of file formats
2. Interacting with these models using the AutoDesk Viewer
3. Displaying mass properties, eg volume and surface area, alongside the viewer (***subject of this post***)

[image: Summary level business process]

### Background

Some file formats have very reliable volume information that is computed and written to the file by the authoring application. For these files, we can access volume as a property via AutoDesk Viewer.

**Other formats, however, do not carry volume information** - at least not in a manner that is openly accessible using tools other than the authoring application (prime example here is SolidWorks). This leaves us with a giant gap to fill - **we need to recompute the model's volume using what's in the file.**

### Known Workarounds and Options

AutoDesk published a blog post detailing an approach for [approximating model volume using triangles of the model inside the viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-volume-and-surface-area-viewer). I think it's an ideal solution for use cases that can afford to trade accuracy for a bump in performance - and it centers everything in the viewer  making development and subsequent maintenance simpler. **This application, however, cannot rely on such approximations.** I'm left reviewing options for leveraging the [AutoDesk Design Automation API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/) to:

1. [Spin up an instance of Inventor](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/)
2. Load the model file
3. Rely on iLogic to trigger a re-computation of the model's part properties (perhaps [like this?](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/inventor-customization/ilogic-to-add-volume-to-user-parameter-and-create-the-param-it/m-p/6049400#M61842))
4. Push that data back to my web application

### Where I Need Help

My understanding is that an [AppBundle](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/task3-upload-appbundle/) and [Activity](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/task4-publish-activity/) are defined ahead of time and then every uploaded model would be [submitted as a work item](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/tutorials/inventor/task6-post-workitem/).

**I am hoping for guidance in:**

- whether this is the *only approach* or whether there are other options worth considering
- [how best to orchestrate the end-to-end process](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/optimize-design-automation-process) from an order of operations/workflow standpoint to maximize performance

### Current Thinking

For example, I'm thinking that my first step after the source file is uploaded is to immediately initialize two parallel processes: the first to translate the source file for the viewer, the second to spin up Inventor and trigger the related downstream process to get volume.

The other option I'm considering is handling all of the work in Inventor - and pushing out an SVF file to the viewer that's enriched with volume data. The advantage of this approach is that my frontend will have only one source for volume data, (it will be in the enriched SVF no matter whether it was supplied in the original file or not).

In an ideal world I'd be able to only invoke the Design Automation API when volume data is missing from the source file - but I'd only know that after translating the file and bringing it back to the viewer. Given that many of our files are created in SolidWorks and other high-end proprietary CAD platforms, my working hypothesis is that we'll be needing to fill in volume gaps more often than not.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct:

- *appbundle* is simply a collection of files (binaries, data) encapsulating a specific Inventor/Revit/3dsMax/AutoCad plugin
- *activity* is a kind of a job template specifying which application should be invoked, which *appbundle* should be loaded into the application, what inputs will be provided to the job, and what outputs will be generated
- *work item* is then a specific instance of a job, binding the *activity* inputs and outputs to specific URLs

There is currently no other way to access the Design Automation functionality other then using these 3 types of entities.

I would suggest the following:

- wherever possible, use the Design Automation for Inventor to compute the precise areas/volumes
- for file formats that cannot be imported into Inventor or any other Design Automation engine, you could use tools like https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils to parse the SVF and compute (a very rough estimate of) the area/surface from the triangular meshes; however, this will be quite computationally expensive, and imprecise

Comment: Thank you Petr for your feedback. I'm wondering if you have any recommendations for avoiding the performance hits I'm concerned about. 

Most users we have seen don't really understand the heavy-lifting that goes on behind-the-scenes, even to render a model in a browser.

Do you think the process of spinning up Inventor, queueing the request, opening the file, doing the recalculation, and getting it back to the browser is a similar "feels like a long time but we can get away with it" type delay? 

Or do you think we're looking at something more than 15-20s?

Comment: I'm afraid it would be the latter. The Design Automation service needs to find an available instance, spin up Inventor with the custom plugin, download the Inventor model from somewhere, run the logic, and upload the results. Even if the logic itself was quick (which I'm not sure about), the rest of the work would still take some time...